# How can I update a field while keeping an specific value of it?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like this:

```
// users 
+----+---------------+ 
| id |      name     |
+----+---------------+
| 1  | Martin        |
| 2  | Peter &#9830; |
| 3  | Ali           |
+----+---------------+
```

All I'm trying to do is updating `name` column and set a new value (`Jack`) for all of records. But I also need to keep `&#9830;` everywhere is. So this is the expected result:

```
+----+---------------+ 
| id |      name     |
+----+---------------+
| 1  | Jack          |
| 2  | Jack &#9830;  |
| 3  | Jack          |
+----+---------------+
```

Also here is my query:

```
UPDATE users SET name = "Jack" WHERE 1;
```

My query doesn't care about `&#9830;`. How can I add it?

Answer (score 3):

Hmmm . . . Is this what you intend?

```
UPDATE users
    SET name = (CASE WHEN name like '% &#9830;' then 'Jack &#9830;' else 'Jack' end)
    WHERE 1;
```

Comment: just what both you and @Gaurav didn't care about `;` which is in the end of `&#9830`? As I've mentioned in my question, the whole `&#9830;` is that specific value.

Comment: Lol we took that as a sentence breaker :)

Answer (score 3):

```
UPDATE users
    SET name = (CASE WHEN name like '% &#9830; %' then 'Jack &#9830;' else 'Jack' END)
    WHERE 1;
```